# throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('chunk',['string','Buffer'],chunk);TypeError[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]:The "chunk" arg must be type string or Buffer

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I am trying to get the contents of a `.json` file using a node js service into an angularjs method. But am getting following **error:**

> _http_outgoing.js:700
>         throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('chunk', ['string', 'Buffer'], chunk);
>         ^
>   TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object
>       at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:700:13)

here are the corresponding code fragments...

**angular controller:** the commented lines are all of those which i have tried and failed with.

```
var currentProcess = "process_1cA";
$scope.storestats = [];
var resAss = $resource('/procs/getstorestats');
var stats = resAss.get({
  process: currentProcess,
  date: date.getFullYear() + "" + m + "" + d
});
stats.$promise.then(function(response) {
  if (response != undefined) {
    //    var r = JSON.parse(response);
    //$scope.storestats.push(r);
    //$scope.storestats.push(r);

    //var r = JSON.parse(response);
    $scope.storestats.push(response);
    //angular.forEach(r, function(value, key) {
    //    $scope.storestats.push({key : value});
    //});
  }
});
```

**NODEJs service:**

```
httpApp.get('/procs/getstorestats', function(req, res, next) {

try {
    fs.readFile(cfg.routestatspath + "storestats-"+req.query.process + "-" + req.query.date + ".json", function (err, data) {
        var msgs1 = JSON.parse(data);
        //var r  = data.toString('utf8');
        var msgs2 = JSON.stringify(msgs1);
        console.log(msgs1);
        res.end(msgs1);
    });
}
catch (err) {
    res.end(err.toString());
}});
```

P.S: **The commented out lines are those which i have tried out with and failed. Also, the commented lines in the node service code snippet, give no error, and when logged show it correctly, but the data when in response of the controllers is blank.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. 2 small changes were needed.. One in the controller, which was to use a "$resource.query" instead of "$resource.get". And in the service, as @jakarella said, had to use the stringified part in the .end();

Controller:

```
                var resAss = $resource('/procs/getstorestats');
                var stats =  resAss.query({process: currentProcess, date: date.getFullYear() + "" + m + "" + d});
                stats.$promise.then(function (response) {
                    $scope.storestats.push(response);
                }
```

Node Service:

```
httpApp.get('/procs/getstorestats', function(req, res, next) {

try {
    fs.readFile(cfg.routestatspath + "storestats-"+req.query.process + "-" + req.query.date + ".json", function (err, data) {
        var msgs1 = JSON.parse(data);
        var msgs2 = JSON.stringify(msgs1);
        console.log(msgs2);
        res.end(msgs2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing a bit here, but I think you just need to change `res.end()` to `res.send()` in your Node code. The "end" method is used when you are streaming chunks of data and then you call `end()` when you're all done. The "send" method is for sending a response in one go and letting Node handle the streaming.

Also, be sure you are sending a string back!

```
httpApp.get('/procs/getstorestats', function(req, res, next) {

  try {
    fs.readFile(cfg.routestatspath + "storestats-"+req.query.process + "-" + req.query.date + ".json", function (err, data) {
        var msgs1 = JSON.parse(data);
        //var r  = data.toString('utf8');
        var msgs2 = JSON.stringify(msgs1);
        console.log(msgs1);
        res.send(msgs2);  // NOTE THE CHANGE to `msg2` (the string version)
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.send(err.toString());  // NOTE THE CHANGE
  }
});
```

Comment: @jakarella, what you told about sending a string was right, coupled with another change. I will post it as an answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error. It was because I was passing process.pid to res.end(). It worked when I changed process.pid to string

```
res.end(process.pid.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'request-promise' library set the json

```
var options = {
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    qs: {
        access_token: 'xxxxx xxxxx' 
    },
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (repos) {

    })
    .catch(function (err) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user6184932, it work

```
try {
    await insertNewDocument(fileNameDB, taskId);
    res.end(process.pid.toString());
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error ocurred", error);
    res.send({
        "code": 400,
        "failed": "error ocurred"
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error using `Node v12 (12.14.1)`.

> Uncaught TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type number

Sample code for context.

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream')
Readable.from(Buffer.from(base64content, 'base64'))
    .pipe( ... )
```

Solution (for my case), was upgrading to `Node v14 (14.17.3)`. e.g.

```sh
nvm use 14
```

- [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating)

Answer (score -1):

in mysql2 the reason for the error is the sql word , sql is a query :
const sql = `select * from tableName`

pool.executeQuery({
sql,
name: 'Error list for given SRC ID',
values: [],
errorMsg: 'Error occurred on fetching '
})
.then(data => {

```
  res.status(200).json({ data })
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('\n \n ==  db , icorp fetching erro ====>  :  ', err.message, '\n \n')
})
```